# correct way to convert mysql to xml file with specific format

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm very new to Mysql and want to convert a database table to xml format like this

```
<Table_Name>
    <table_data id="1" file_path="d:\...." />
    <table_data id="2" file_path="d:\..." />
</Table_Name>
```

I have tried this by using the below query but, I'm getting few row in the table.

```
SELECT   CONCAT('<Table_Name>',
   GROUP_CONCAT('<table_data id="', t.id, '" file_path="', t.path, '"/>'  SEPARATOR ''),
   '</Table_Name>')
        FROM Table_Name t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the procedures from this web site as was able to do so by following the steps but it uses php .
Link:http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/mysql-to-xml-php/